# How to access child view in layout in Custom View Group?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

The picture below shows my custom view.

[My Custom Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K67A7.png)

I want add custom buttons in child layout in my custom view.
So, I tried like below.

My CustomView is a ConstraintLayout and the code is

```kotlin
class MyCustomLayout(
    context: Context,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attributeSet) {

    private var binding: MyCustomLayoutBinding

    init {
        binding = HarusekkiBaseToolbarBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(context),
            this,
            true
        )
    }

    override fun addView(child: View?, index: Int, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) {
        child ?: return

        if (child is HaruSekkiToolbarButton) {
            binding.buttonContainer.addView(child, index, params)
        } else {
            super.addView(child, index, params)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I wrote xml of fragment

```xml
<ConstraintLayout
    .../>
    <MyCustomLayout
        ...>
        <MyCustomButton 
            android:id="@+id/myButton1 
            ... />
        <MyCustomButton 
            android:id="@+id/myButton2
            ... />

    </MyCustomLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

When I access MyCustomButton in Fragment Class like

```kotlin
    binding.myButton1.do_somthing
```

it returns null.

How to I get MyCustomButton? Is addView method what I override wrong?

I've also changed the addView function in MyCustomLayout as follows.

```kotlin
    private val childViews = mutableListOf<View>()

    override fun addView(child: View?, index: Int, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) {
        child ?: return

        childViews.add(child)
        if (child is HaruSekkiToolbarButton) {
            binding.toolbarButtonContainer.addView(child, index, params)
        } else {
            super.addView(child, index, params)
        }
    }

    override fun getChildCount(): Int {
        return childViews.size
    }

    override fun getChildAt(index: Int): View {
        return childViews[index]
    }

    override fun indexOfChild(child: View?): Int {
        return childViews.indexOf(child)
    }
```

However, it didn't work well with ClassCastException.

(java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams)

Plz Help me!

Comment: Can you describe why you need a custom layout? I think in your case the horizontal LinearLayout will work as an image

Comment: That Custom Layout will be my Toolbar. My app has variable fragments and i want to reduce duplicate codes by using custom view.